# phpredis PHP Redis cluster - too many mistakes in our program

Tags: php, redis, cluster-computing

Error message:

```
[2018-08-08 14:36:26 *176089.7] ERROR   zm_deactivate_swoole (ERROR 503): Fatal error: Uncaught RedisClusterException: Timed out attempting to find data in the correct node! in /var/www/pt_target/Newtrade/SwooleCommand/Controller/SwooleServerController.class.php:221
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/pt_target/Newtrade/SwooleCommand/Controller/SwooleServerController.class.php(221): RedisCluster->hgetall('ws_client_servi...')
```

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve, provide context and edit your question so it looks like a question. That will make a lot easier for devs willing to help solve your issue.

Comment: We use cluster mode, but the client links redis, and the following reports are wrong.
"timed out attempting to find data in the correct node!"
How to solve the mistake ？

Comment: Start by checking configuration, a timeout is probably unability to get connected to service.

Comment: Please put the information into the question (by editing it), not by answering in comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Your question is about to be closed for a lack of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And please respond (and take action) to ***all*** of my comments (3), not just the last one. Thanks in advance.